# Задача «Количество совпадающих пар». Как работает решение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сама задача с Питонтьютора:

Дан список чисел. Посчитайте, сколько в нем пар элементов, равных друг другу. Считается, что любые два элемента, равные друг другу образуют одну пару, которую необходимо посчитать.

Я решил ее намного более громоздко, и после решения там показываются еще решения других участников. Там я увидел очень интересное решение всего в 2 строки. Но я так и не смог в нем разобраться.

```
a = input().split() # например 1 1 1 1 1
print(sum(a.count(x) - 1 for x in a) // 2)
```

Я вроде знаю что такое генераторы, да и что такое sum и a.count(x) по отдельности, но тут я это не могу осознать. Пробовал даже с помощью визуализатора. Кто нибудь может обьяснить как это работает?

Comment: По мне это решение не очень красивое, ну да ладно,  мы по сути для каждого элемента считаем сколько таких же других (поэтому и -1) а потом сумму по всем делим на 2 (каждую пару 2 раза считали). Но правильное решение имхо должно содержать словарь и итерация именно по словарю с формулой x(x-1)/2.

Comment: А как ты определяешь критерии правильного решения?

Comment: Ну я не сильный знаток питона. Но это решение попахивает квадратичной сложностью,и, например при 100.000 чисел на входе может работать неоправданно долго.

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда мое изначальное решение было ещё хуже:)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал разобраться с counter-ом, он тут идеален.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмём предложенный пример с пятью единицами.
Первая единица образует пару с четырьмя другими единицами. Это подсчитывается через a.count(x)-1. Количество пар находится для каждого элемента через for x in a и складывается через sum(). Сумма получается в два раза больше, т.к. каждая пара учитывается 2 раза (например, первый элемент со вторым, а потом наоборот), поэтому добавлено деление на 2.